# golang s3 download to buffer using s3manager.downloader

Tags: go, amazon-s3

I'm using the Amazon s3 SDK to download files like below:

```
file, err := os.Create("/tmp/download_file")
downloader := s3manager.NewDownloader(session.New(&aws.Config{
                                 Region: aws.String("us-west-2")}))
numBytes, err := downloader.Download(file,
    &s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucketName),
        Key:    aws.String(fileName),
    })
```

It downloads to a file.

How do I get the download content into a `[]byte` slice (buffer) directly. 
I tried something like:

```
var tBuf bytes.Buffer
tBufIo := bufio.NewWriter(&tBuf)
```

instead of "file". But I get an error for `io.WriterAt` interface

> cannot use *tBufIo (type bufio.Writer) as type io.WriterAt in argument to downloader.Download

Answer (score 48):

Found it from the link
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Golang-Nuts/4z8rcWEZ8Os

```
buff := &aws.WriteAtBuffer{}
downloader := s3manager.NewDownloader(session.New(&aws.Config{
                                      Region: aws.String(S3_Region)}))
numBytes, err := downloader.Download(buff,....
data := buff.Bytes() // now data is my []byte array
```

Works and fits the need.

See also: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/#WriteAtBuffer

Comment: You should accept your answer. You can do it now since it has been more than 2 days.

Comment: Using an empty buffer is very inefficient. It is 20x times faster for 30MB file if you preallocate memory. See https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/pull/483

Comment: Yep. You can also download the HeadObject to allocate exactly as much as you need.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running AWS SDK v2 then you can create a WriterAt like this

```
import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/credentials"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/s3/manager"
)
func DownloadS3File(objectKey string, bucket string, s3Client *s3.Client) ([]byte, error) {

    buffer := manager.NewWriteAtBuffer([]byte{})

    downloader := manager.NewDownloader(s3Client)

    numBytes, err := downloader.Download(context.TODO(), buffer, &s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Key:    aws.String(objectKey),
    })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if numBytes < 1 {
        return nil, errors.New("zero bytes written to memory")
    }

    return buffer.Bytes(), nil
}
```